# Rails: renaming a controller and corresponding model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rename, batch-rename

Is there an easy way to rename a controller and model in my app and all the instances in the corresponding code?

I'm using textmate, would this be as simple as using the replace function and replacing the word Post with Report?

Comment: do you already have code or did you just run generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using textmate, use 'command-shift-f" to look for a string throughout your entire project.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change the name of the **Controller** and the associated **Model**, **Views**, **Helpers**, **Tests** & **Routes** directories, file names, class names & the names in the class definitions.

I found two ways to do this but before you try anything I recommend you **back-up your app**, preferably with a Software Version Control system like Git & Github.com.

Your first option is to do it manually & there is a good explanation on how to do this here: [How to rename rails controller and model in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924124/how-to-rename-rails-controller-and-model-in-a-project)

Another way is to `destroy` your controller & model, and then `generate` a new one, this will remove all the files which were generated the first time round & replace them with new ones. Michael Hartl explains this solution well in his online guide to Ruby on Rails here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sidebar-undoing_things

This is the solution I followed when I needed to make this change to my app, I needed to replace a MVC scaffold I generated called `board` with a new one called `product`.

**1. First**

I made a back-up of the work I did in the layout of the board view, **app/views/boards/index.html.erb**

**2. Then**

I ran the below rails commands in the terminal window.

```
$ rake db:rollback

$ rails destroy scaffold board name:string description:text image:string price:decimal

$ rails generate scaffold product product_type:string name:string description:text image:string price:decimal

$ rake db:migrate
```

**3. Finally**

I copied my backed-up **boards/index.html.erb** file into the newly generated **app/views/products/index.html.erb** & did a *find & replace* in my text editor on this file to replace `board` with `product`.

I think the second option is much more reliable & quicker but it’s important to make this change early on in your project before you make too many manual changes to the code.  It would be better to just take a little more time planning your MVC names & database tables properly before you start your project.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **rails_refactor gem** to rename controller, model, etc 
for more info check https://github.com/jcrisp/rails_refactor

Answer (score 2):

To rename controller and model use this gem https://github.com/jcrisp/rails_refactor

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You can rename it that way, but you'll also need to rename the files as well or Rails won't know where to look for the files corresponding to the new Report model/controller/etc.

Comment: And you'll also likely want to rename the variables within your controller(s), especially if you are using partials that expect a certain naming convention.