# Safely rename Controller, its Model, and its migrations in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to rename a controller in Laravel, its Model and its migrations.

I can do it manually, but the problem is that I'll spend a significant amount of time (especially renaming the migrations files'name, the content inside the migration files, and the table 'migrations' in which Laravel keeps track of the migrations).

I can do it now as I have few migrations. So far, the app is small (I just created it to get started with `Laravel`); I have only a dashboard, a user controller, and an articles controller(that allows users to create and to edit their articles, and allows guests to only see the articles). However, what If that happens again and I have, for example, 30 migrations? I may accidentally mess up everything and cause bugs.

Can I rename a controller automatically? If yes, how I do that? If not, is there something I have to pay special attention when renaming the controller manually? So it won't cause problems after renaming it.

**Note**:
I'm a newbie in Laravel and in StackOverflow, so I'm sorry if my question seems a fool; just don't be rude with me.

Comment: I doubt if there's a way to automate all this process. However you can use `PHPStorm` that can safely rename + refactor class names but not the migration files. You've to do that manually as per my information.

Comment: Thank you Zeshan Khattak. Indeed, I had to rename the controller manually. It was chaos; I don't recommend anyone to do that; it is better to `rollback` the migrations, delete the controller, and create a new controller than renaming everything.

Comment: I think your answer is here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415865/11038906

Comment: Without knowing your app specifics, this is actually a pretty straight-forward process. The Controller and Model can just be renamed, and their usages updated to the new name. The Migration is a little tougher - you should leave your old migrations in place, as-is. Create new migrations to update your table and column names.

Comment: migrations are used for database changes. Controllers/Models are php files and can be refactored separately. Im not sure how these 2 are related with such little info about your app.

Comment: Why would you want to rename the migration files? The renaming itself (of the table, red) is a new migration, I'd argue

Comment: @Stratadox, I didn't think about this solution. Indeed, it is a better idea to create new migrations to rename the tables than to rename the migrations themselves. I already renamed the Controller and all its related stuff, but next time I'll follow your advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: Don't rename your migrations. Instead, add a `table rename` migration.

Long answer:

**Migrations** are a chronological list of the changes made to your database. They are named `migrations` because they tend to cause a mass movement of data: the data **migrates** from one structure to another. Renaming a table *is one of such migrations*.

One of the benefits of having migrations is the ability to roll back the database changes. Assuming your source code is under version control (git, svn, etc) and a release appears faulty after launch, you can simply run a "down migration" and restore the previous (working) version of the application while you work on a fix.

In order for the above scheme to work, it's important to keep your migration files intact. Ideally, you don't ever *change* a migration: instead you'd **add a new migration** that incorporates whatever you wanted to change.

To conclude with an example, if you initially named your model `Foo`, you'd have a migration that comes down to

```
create_foo migration:
up: create table foo
down: delete table foo
```

Some time later you figure out you've accidentally named it `Foo` instead of `Bar` and rename it. You'd add something that comes down to:

```
rename_foo_to_bar migration:
up: rename table foo to bar
down: rename table bar to foo
```

Yet later it turns out `Bar` should obviously have been `Baz`:

```
rename_bar_to_baz migration:
up: rename table bar to baz
down: rename table baz to bar
```

...but it turns out the release has a bug, so you revert your code and run the down migration

After fixing the bug, you might need to apply a bug-fixing migration:

```
fix_some_bug migration
up: rename column or something
down: restore the bug
```

When releasing the bugfix, the database is still at `rename_foo_to_bar`, so during deployment, both `rename_bar_to_baz` and `fix_some_bug` are applied.

By using this system, you can keep your database in sync with the current version of the code you're running.

Don't use down-migrations lightly, though, there's often a risk of losing data.

Comment: Thanks! That is a good recommendation! I should have done that and I'll keep that in mind. Still, I won't mark it as the accepted answer because I'm looking for an automatic way to rename the controller and everything else related to it.

Comment: I don't believe Laravel has an automatic command for this, although it should be possible to create one yourself. It might not be necessary to do so, though: many editors have a feature to rename a class **and all it's usages**. To rename a controller, that would leave you only with updating the routes.

Comment: Notice that controllers don't talk to the database directly; it shouldn't be necessary to use a migration or to change the database at all if you're renaming a controller.

Comment: Stratadox do you know how to rename a class and all it's usages in vscode? I tried `refactoring`, but it actually does not run.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Now, after some weeks using Laravel, I realized my question was not very smart and I should never think in renaming migrations. Still, If someday someone comes with a way to rename the Models, Routes, Controller, etc all together, then I'll accept that answer

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the visual studio editor, especially for php. I don't think it was a dumb question by the way; I'm sure you're not the only one struggling with these concepts - nobody is born with all the programming knowledge.